# The truth and lie mess

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, liars

There are two persons with special traits such that :

- One speaks only lies and no truth on Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday and all truth rest of the week.
- The other speaks only lies and no truth on Thursday, Friday, Saturday and all truth rest of the week.

They both meet up at a coffee shop, What is the probability that both will say "I spoke a lie yesterday"??

Quite simple puzzle but yet fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability is

> $\frac{1}{7}$

For the first person :

> **Monday** : The fact that he said a lie yesterday is wrong but he is lying  so he can say "I spoke a lie yesterday"
>  **Tuesday / Wednesday** : The fact that he said a lie yesterday is true and he he lying so he can't say it
>  **Thursday** : The fact that he said a lie yesterday is true and he says the truth so he so he can say it
>  **Friday / Saturday / Sunday** : The fact that he said a lie yesterday is wrong and he says the truth so he so he can't say it
>  ---> He can only says this sentence on Monday and Thursday

For the second person :

> It's the same but with a 3 days shift so he can say this only on Thursday and Sunday.

The probability is :

> $\frac{1}{7}$ which is the probability that they meet on Thursday

Note that :

> this assume that they speak every day

Comment: Bingo!! was expecting to be answered in a few mins

Comment: Why do we have to assume that they speak everyday ?